.NET Core app looks for package assembly path without dll extension
My ASP.NET Core app references the PDFSharp package. This package creates 6 dll files:

PdfSharp.Charting.dll
PdfSharp.dll
PdfSharp.Quality.dll
PdfSharp.Snippets.dll
PdfSharp.System.dll
PdfSharp.WPFonts.dll

The app compiles and runs successfully, but when an action is done that triggers code referencing this package, it throws the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharp.System, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified

It seems to be looking for the file without the .dll extension.
Process Monitor shows that it successfully loads PdfSharp.dll, but loading PdfSharp.System results in NAME NOT FOUND.
Process monitor output
Some solutions for this kind of issue suggest editing the HintPath in the .csproj file. My .csproj file doesn't contain any HintPath, and the portion related to this package looks like this:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PDFsharp" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

I don't know the right way to update this with a hint path, but I tried the following, and it made no difference (Process Monitor shows no attempt to load the file with the dll extension):
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PDFsharp" Version="6.0.0" />
    <Reference Include="PDFsharp.System">
        <HintPath>.\PDFsharp.System.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

If I change the file name from PdfSharp.System.dll to PdfSharp.System, then the file is loaded successfully and the app works as expected.
However, I don't think this is the right way to solve this problem. Why is the app trying to load the file without the .dll extension? How is this determined? Is there a way to get the app to look for the file with the .dll extension?

In your .csproj file, check that the "hintpath" for the reference includes the file name with the extension.

@Kevin, my .csproj file doesn't contain any hint paths. My attempt to add one didn't work (I updated the post with more info).

Yeah, with packagereference tags you won't have hint paths.  and they are usually much easier to work with than the old reference tags.  Does your app compile, and then get errors at runtime? or does it fail to compile?

@Kevin The app compiles and runs just fine. The error is only thrown at runtime when I do an action that triggers code referencing the package.

Assemblies have names that are distinct from the file name. That's what the PDFSharp.System identifier is.

@JoelCoehoorn Is there a way to tell the system to look for the PdfSharp.System assembly in the PdfSharp.System.dll file?
